# How can I replace variable names in equations in R?

Tags: r

Currently, I'm trying to parse equations between two different text files produced by different software. Let's say I have the following strings:

```
test_vector <- c("a*xa", "a+ax", "xa+a", "x*a", "(a)*(axa)")
```

I want to replace the variable **a** with the number 0.5

If I try

```
stringr::str_replace_all(test_vector, "a", "0.5")
```

I get

```
[1] "0.5*x0.5"        "0.5+0.5x"        "x0.5+0.5"        "x*0.5"           "(0.5)*(0.5x0.5)"
```

However, I expect

```
 [1] "0.5*xa"      "0.5+ax"      "xa+0.5"      "x*0.5"       "(0.5)*(axa)"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `stringr::str_replace_all(test_vector, "\\ba\\b", "0.5")`

Comment: I'm reopening because these strings are parsable, so the variables can be substituted and it's not necessarily a regex problem

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non regex solution that parses the strings, substitutes the variable in the expression, and then deparses it as a string again :

```r
str_substitute <- function(x, ...){
  sapply(parse(text= x), function(x) deparse(do.call(substitute, list(x, list(...)))))
}
test_vector <- c("a*xa", "a+ax", "xa+a", "x*a", "(a)*(axa)") 
str_substitute(test_vector, a = 0.5 )
#> [1] "0.5 * xa"      "0.5 + ax"      "xa + 0.5"      "x * 0.5"      
#> [5] "(0.5) * (axa)"
str_substitute(test_vector, xa = quote(y), ax =  quote(z), a = .5)
#> [1] "0.5 * y"       "0.5 + z"       "y + 0.5"       "x * 0.5"      
#> [5] "(0.5) * (axa)"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that you might get additional spaces or have spaces removed here and there with some inputs

Answer (score 0):

Try with `gsub`, i.e., `gsub("\\ba\\b","0.5",test_vector)`